# Javaのメソッドに関する質問です。 以下の書き方を教えてください。

Tags: java

【動物と鳴き声の一覧】
動物 「鳴く」などの動詞
犬（dog） bark（吠える）
猫（cat） meow（吠える）
鳥（bird） sing （歌う感じでさえずる）
羊（sheep） bleat（メーと鳴く）
豚（pig） grunt （ブーブー鳴く）

コンソールには以下を表示させたいです。

私の名前は、山田太郎です！
これから、私のペットを紹介します！
名前は、ポチです！
2020/07/27で7歳になります！
わんわん！

作成中のコードは下記です。

【メインメソッド】

```
package animal;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 問① 下部の問④のメソッドを作成後、自身の姓名を引数にセットしなさい
        Main.printMyName("山田", "太郎");

        // 問② 以下の変数に適切な値を格納しなさい。
        String name = pet;
        int age = 7;
    }

    // 問③ 以下の条件で、任意の動物クラスをインスタンス化し、適切なメソッドを呼び出しなさい。
    // 1: メソッドの引数には、問②で作成したローカル変数を使用すること。
    void show() {
        System.out.println("私の名前は" + name + "です！。");
    }

    void showAnimal() {
        System.out.println("こから、私のペットを紹介します！");
        Animal animal = new Animal();
    }

    // 問④ 以下1〜3の条件で、自身の名前とペットを紹介する旨の内容をコンソールへ出力する printMyName メソッドを作成しなさい。
    //
    // - 1. アクセス修飾子 = private
    // - 2. 引数:
    // - 2-1. 姓（セイ）
    // - 2-2. 名（メイ）
    // - 3. 戻り値 = なし
    private static void printMyName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("名前は" + fullName(firstName, lastName) + "です");
    }
  }
}
```

【任意の動物クラスメソッド】

```
package animal;

// 問⑥ 以下の条件で、任意の動物クラスを作成しなさい。
// - 1: 対象の動物は、backlogの【動物と鳴き声の一覧】を参考とすること
// - 2: Animalを継承すること

public class 任意の動物クラス名 {

    public void Animal() {
        super();
    }

    public void Animal(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

⇩

public class 任意の動物クラス名 extends Animal {

    public 任意の動物クラス名(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    public class dog extends Animal {

        public dog(String name, int age) {
            super(name, age);
        }

    // 問⑦ 以下の条件で、当該クラスに合う動物の鳴き声をコンソールへ出力するメソッドを作成しなさい。
    // - 1: 対象の動物の鳴き声は、backlogの【動物と鳴き声の一覧】を参考とすること
    // - 2. アクセス修飾子 = protected
    // - 3. 引数 = なし
    // - 4. 戻り値 = なし
    class Dog extends Animal {
        public void bark() {
            System.out.println("わんわん！");
        }
    }
}
```

【アニマルメソッド】

```
package animal;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Animal() {
    }

    public Animal(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    protected int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    protected void introduce() {
        System.out.println("名前は、" + this.getName() + "です！");

        // 問⑤ 以下の条件で、Calendarクラスを使用して、yyyy/MM/dd形式で誕生日を取得しなさい
        // - 1: Calendarクラスの変数名 = calendar
        // - 2: 実行する日より「5ヶ月15日後」の日付を表示しなさい
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ここへ日付のフォーマットを記述");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) + "で" + this.getAge() + "歳になります！");
    }
}
```

Comment: コメント欄は議論をする場ではないため、この会話をチャットに移動しました： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139966/discussion-on-question-by-roger-java-

Answer (score 1):

実行環境：paiza.io
※paiza.ioに合わせた書き方になっている可能性があります。

Main.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 問1 下部の問④のメソッドを作成後、自身の姓名を引数にセットしなさい
        // Main.printMyName("山田", "太郎");

        // 問2 以下の変数に適切な値を格納しなさい。
        String name = "ポチ";
        int age = 7;
        
        show(fullName("山田", "太郎"));
        showAnimal(name, age);
    }
    
    // 問3 以下の条件で、任意の動物クラスをインスタンス化し、適切なメソッドを呼び出しなさい。
    // 1: メソッドの引数には、問2で作成したローカル変数を使用すること。
    static void show(String name) {
        System.out.println("私の名前は" + name + "です！");
    }
    
    static void showAnimal(String name, int age) {
        System.out.println("これから、私のペットを紹介します！");
        Animal animal = new Dog(name, age);
        animal.introduce();
        animal.bark();
    }

    // 問4 以下1〜3の条件で、自身の名前とペットを紹介する旨の内容をコンソールへ出力する printMyName メソッドを作成しなさい。
    //
    // - 1. アクセス修飾子 = private
    // - 2. 引数:
    // - 2-1. 姓（セイ）
    // - 2-2. 名（メイ）
    // - 3. 戻り値 = なし
    private static void printMyName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("名前は" + fullName(firstName, lastName) + "です");
    }
    
    private static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Animal.java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Animal() {
    }

    public Animal(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    protected int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    protected void introduce() {
        System.out.println("名前は、" + this.getName() + "です！");

        // 問⑤ 以下の条件で、Calendarクラスを使用して、yyyy/MM/dd形式で誕生日を取得しなさい
        // - 1: Calendarクラスの変数名 = calendar
        // - 2: 実行する日より「5ヶ月15日後」の日付を表示しなさい
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) + "で" + this.getAge() + "歳になります！");
    }
    
    protected void bark() {}
}
```

Dog.java

```
// 問7 以下の条件で、当該クラスに合う動物の鳴き声をコンソールへ出力するメソッドを作成しなさい。
// - 1: 対象の動物の鳴き声は、backlogの【動物と鳴き声の一覧】を参考とすること
// - 2. アクセス修飾子 = protected
// - 3. 引数 = なし
// - 4. 戻り値 = なし
public class Dog extends Animal {
    
    public Dog(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }
    
    protected void bark() {
        System.out.println("わんわん！");
    }
}
```

出力結果

```
私の名前は山田 太郎です！
これから、私のペットを紹介します！
名前は、ポチです！
2022/10/16で7歳になります！
わんわん！
```

---

Main.javaを修正しました。

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 問1 下部の問④のメソッドを作成後、自身の姓名を引数にセットしなさい
        // Main.printMyName("太郎", "山田");

        // 問2 以下の変数に適切な値を格納しなさい。
        String name = "ポチ";
        int age = 7;
        
        printMyName("山田", "太郎", name, age);
    }
    
    // 問3 以下の条件で、任意の動物クラスをインスタンス化し、適切なメソッドを呼び出しなさい。
    // 1: メソッドの引数には、問2で作成したローカル変数を使用すること。
    static void show(String name) {
        System.out.println("私の名前は" + name + "です！");
    }
    
    static void showAnimal(String name, int age) {
        System.out.println("これから、私のペットを紹介します！");
        Animal animal = new Dog(name, age);
        animal.introduce();
        animal.bark();
    }

    // 問4 以下1〜3の条件で、自身の名前とペットを紹介する旨の内容をコンソールへ出力する printMyName メソッドを作成しなさい。
    //
    // - 1. アクセス修飾子 = private
    // - 2. 引数:
    // - 2-1. 姓（セイ）
    // - 2-2. 名（メイ）
    // - 3. 戻り値 = なし
    private static void printMyName(String firstName, String lastName, String petName, int petAge) {
        System.out.println("名前は" + fullName(firstName, lastName) + "です!");
        showAnimal(petName, petAge);
    }
    
    private static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: 「コンパイルエラーになってしまうのですが」とはどのファイルのどの行で、どんなエラーでしょうか？（paiza.ioでは出力結果が表示されておりコンパイルエラーは起きていません）

Comment: 申し訳ありません。// 問⑥ 以下の条件で、任意の動物クラスを作成しなさい。
// - 1: 対象の動物は、backlogの【動物と鳴き声の一覧】を参考とすること
// - 2: Animalを継承すること

Comment: 問⑥の回答は自分が書いたコードですとエラーになるため回答をご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: エラー内容、以下に追記いたします。

Comment: 問⑥のコード修正いたしました。super();　super(name, age);の部分で、「コンストラクター呼び出しは、コンストラクター内の最初のステートメントである必要がありま
す」とエラーが出てきてしまうのですが、どのように修正すればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 私の回答のコードそのままでそのエラーが出ますか？

Comment: すみません、merino様の問⑥のコードが見当たらないのですが、どちらに記載ありますでしょうか。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。先程のコードは見当たりましたが、「私の名前は山田 太郎です！」がコンソールに2度表示され、「2022/10/16で7歳になります！」
「わんわん！」がコンソールに表示されない状態です。

Comment: Javaの実行環境は何をお使いでしょうか？

Comment: こちらではjavacコマンドとjavaコマンドでも回答通りの出力となりました。

Comment: エクリプスです。

Comment: メインメソッドのshow(fullName("山田", "太郎"));を削除したら、「私の名前は山田 太郎です！」は、ちゃんと1度だけ表示になりました。

Comment: 度々すみません、やはりmerino様の問⑥のコードが見当たらないのですが、ご回答をごご教示いただけますでしょうか。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 「メインメソッドのshow(fullName("山田", "太郎"));を削除したら、「私の名前は山田 太郎です！」は、ちゃんと1度だけ表示になりました。」ということであれば、質問者さんのコードと私が回答したコードとは同じものではないようです。一度私の回答したコードをそのままコピーして実行確認していただけないでしょうか？（Main.java、Animal.java、Dog.javaの3つ）

Comment: Dog.javaの問⑥のコードをご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: Dogクラスそのものが回答だと思いますが違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。

Comment: 私の名前は山田 太郎です！
私の名前は山田 太郎です！
これから、私のペットを紹介します！
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 トークン "." に構文エラーがあります。このトークンの後には @ を指定する必要があります
 構文エラーがあります。"SimpleName" を挿入して QualifiedName を完了してください
 構文エラーがあります。"Identifier (" を挿入して MethodHeaderName を完了してください
 構文エラーがあります。")" を挿入して MethodDeclaration を完了してください

 at animal.Animal.<init>(Animal.java:45)
 at animal.任意の動物クラス名.<init>(任意の動物クラス名.java:10)
 at animal.Main.showAnimal(Main.java:27)
 at animal.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Comment: merino様にご教示いただいたコードですと、以上の表示とエラーになる状態でございます。

Comment: 問⑤の日付に関するコードですと、以下のエラー表示が出る状態です。

Comment: この行に複数マーカーがあります
 
- 構文エラーがあります。")" を挿入して MethodDeclaration を完了してください
 
- 構文エラーがあります。"SimpleName" を挿入して QualifiedName を完了してください
 
- 構文エラーがあります。"Identifier (" を挿入して MethodHeaderName を完了してくださ
い
 
- トークン "." に構文エラーがあります。このトークンの後には @ を指定する必要があります

Comment: 以下、問⑤のエラーになるコードです。

Comment: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy/MM/dd");System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())+"で"+this.getAge()+"歳になります！");

    protected void bark() {
    }
}

Comment: 別でご質問募集し、ご回答いただきましたクラスに関する日付のコードは、今回どこのクラスにも記載しない感じでしょうか。

Comment: public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) + "で" + "歳になります！");
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    
    }
}

Comment: 以上のコードになります。

Comment: 「任意の動物クラス名」などという言葉は私が書いたコードにはありません。何かコードが混ざっていませんか？ 私の回答したコードをそのままコピーして、Main.java、Animal.java、Dog.javaを作成してMain.javaをコンパイルして実行してみてください。

Comment: ファイル名を「任意の動物クラス名.Java」から「Dog.java」に変更し、コード全文をコピーし、Main.javaをコンパイルして実行してみましたが、エラー内容は先程と変わらない状況です。

Comment: 問①の回答が、//でコメント表示にされているかと思うのですが、そうせずとも「私の名前は山田 太郎です！ 」を1度だけ表示させたいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: at animal.Animal.<init>(Animal.java:45)
 at animal.Dog.<init>(Dog.java:10)
 at animal.Main.showAnimal(Main.java:27)
 at animal.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Comment: Main.javaをコンパイルすると以上のエラー表示になります。

Comment: printMyName()を使用しなければならない、ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうでございます。

Comment: そうなるとshow()関数は不要な気がしますが、printMyName()とshow()の関係はどうなっているのでしょうか？ show()もfullName()も使用しなくて良いということでしょうか？ 制約条件がよく分からないので質問者さん自身でコードの微調整は行っていただく必要があるかと思います。

Comment: show(fullName("山田", "太郎"));
        showAnimal(name, age);を削除しましたら、「私の名前は山田 太郎です！ 」のみしかコンソールに表示されない状態です。

Comment: printMyNameは使用必須で show()とfullName()は使用しなくても良いです。

Comment: 質問文をよく読むと「自身の名前とペットを紹介する旨の内容をコンソールへ出力する printMyName メソッドを作成しなさい。」とあります。printMyName メソッドの中でペットの名前と年齢も出力する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: merino様　コメント遅くなりました。仰る通りです。

Comment: 現状ペットの名前・年齢・鳴き声が出力されない状態です。

Comment: printMyName メソッドの引数は「2-1. 姓（セイ）、2-2. 名（メイ）」だけと決まっているのですよね？ペットの名前と年齢はmainメソッドの中にありますが、それらはprintMyNameメソッドからは呼び出せないと思いますが、この条件でコードを作成しなさいとの課題なのでしょうか？

Comment: merino様　仰る通りです。

Comment: String name と int age は mainメソッドの中に書かなければならないのですか？

Comment: その通りでございます。

Comment: だとすると解けない気がしますので出題者に確認された方が良いのでは？

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。printMyName メソッドの中でペットの名前と年齢も出力する必要はありますが、直前2件のご質問は必須ではないということでした。

Comment: そうであれば、ペットの名前と年齢をprintMyNameメソッドに引数として渡してshowAnimalメソッドを呼ぶ感じでしょうか？showメソッドからprintMyNameを呼ぶようにして、mainメソッド内でshowメソッドを呼べば完成でしょうか。確認まではしていませんが大体はこのような感じかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その通りだと思います。大変お手数ですが、修正コードをご教示いたでけますでしょうか。大変申し訳ございません。

Comment: merino様　Main.javaの修正、誠にありがとうございました。問①はコメント表示にするのがNGなのですが、コメント表示にする以外の方法はなさそうでしょうか？

Comment: また問③のanimal.bark();のコードでbarkに赤線が入りコンパイルできない状態です。

Comment: コメントアウトNGの件はMain.printMyName("太郎", "山田");のことですか？　問1と問2の並びはこの通りですか？現状Main.printMyNameからnameとageは呼び出せませんが？

Comment: merino様　仰る通りです。ちなみにprintMyNameを使用しなければ、コメントアウトせずにコーディング可能でしょうか？

Comment: すみませんが「printMyNameを使用しなければ、コメントアウトせずにコーディング可能でしょうか？ 」の意味が分かりません。ちなみに私のところでは「また問③のanimal.bark();のコードでbarkに赤線が入りコンパイルできない状態です。」は発生せずにコンパイル＆実行が可能ですので私が回答したコードと質問者さんがコンパイルしているコードとの間に何か差異があるようです。ですのでコンパイルできない原因は私にはわかりかねます。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。質問を変えます。各メソッド上部にあるimportの記述は必須なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「import java.util.*;」は不要ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。承知いたしました。

Comment: 現状メインメソッドで以下のエラーが出る状態です。解決方法ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: ・ローカル変数nameの値は使用されていません。
・ローカル変数ageの値は使用されていません。
・メソッドbark()は型Animalで未定義です。
・コンソールに「名前は山田 太郎です！」だけ表示される状態。

Comment: Rogerさんがコンパイルされているコードは何でしょうか？私の回答のコードをコンパイル＆実行しても「コンソールに「名前は山田 太郎です！」だけ表示」となりますか？Paiza.ioで試していただいても同じ結果でしょうか？（そんなはずはないと思いますが）

Comment: コメント遅くなりました。仰る通りPaiza.ioでmerino様のコードをコンパイル＆実行すれば全て表示されるのですが、エクリプスではpackage animal;を各クラスの冒頭に記載する必要があり、全て表示されない状態です。

Comment: Eclipseは使用していないため特有の現象については分かりません。Eclipseを使用しなければならないのでしょうか？ javacでのコンパイルではダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: Eclipseを使用しなければならないです。

Comment: それではEclipseでのJavaのコンパイルについての質問を新たにされた方が良いかもしれませんね。